# Hadoop 2.2 - datanode doesn't start up

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I had Hadoop 2.4 this morning (see my previous 2 questions). Now I removed it and installed 2.2 as I had issues with 2.4, and also as I think 2.2 is the latest stable release. Now I followed the tutorial here:

http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html?m=1

I am pretty sure I did everything right but I am facing similar issues again.

When I run jps it is obvious that the data node is not starting up.

What am I doing wrong again?

```
hduser@test02:~$ start-dfs.sh
14/06/06 18:12:45 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-test02.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-test02.out
localhost: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
localhost: It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-test02.out
0.0.0.0: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
0.0.0.0: It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/06/06 18:13:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
hduser@test02:~$ jps
2201 Jps
hduser@test02:~$ jps
2213 Jps
hduser@test02:~$ start-yarn
start-yarn: command not found
hduser@test02:~$ start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-test02.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-test02.out
hduser@test02:~$ jps
2498 NodeManager
2264 ResourceManager
2766 Jps
hduser@test02:~$ jps
2784 Jps
2498 NodeManager
2264 ResourceManager
hduser@test02:~$ jps
2498 NodeManager
2264 ResourceManager
2796 Jps
hduser@test02:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I took these instructions from the tutorial too literally.

> Paste following between `<configuration>`
>       fs.default.name
>       hdfs://localhost:9000

I suspected this was wrong while doing it but still I did it.
It seemed incorrect as the `core-site.xml` file is in XML format.
So actually, it needs to look like this.

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

Changing it to this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with DataNode not starting up. What I did was reformat the namenode, then restarted the cluster. Then, running `jps` confirmed that data node was started up.

This can be caused by placing the HDFS directory in your "home" directory (on a linux box) since upon starting up and shutting down the OS affects these folders (not exactly sure how, but to prevent this problem in the future, move the HDFS directory out of your home directory).

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: HDFS folder was not in my home directory. I fixed it somehow (not quite sure how as I did 2 changes) but now I have another issue: the web monitoring shows 0 active nodes. I submitted a task but noone is processing it, it seems.

Comment: Installing this Hadoop monster is not easy, even the most simple configuration is full of surprises, it seems...

Comment: So now... the NodeManager is not starting up! Great!