# Hadoop 2.4.1 Installation not running properly on Ubuntu 14.04?Node manager VM stack guard error

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, 64-bit

Im trying to set up Hadoop 2.4.1 multi cluster on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit machine. After starting the Hadoop daemon,when i jps i couldn't see my node manger running. When i check the node manager log ,i got the follwoing error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/share/hadoop-2.4.1/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to resolve this issue??
I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091434/hadoop-2-2-datanode-doesnt-start-up)
but im getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop 2.x native libraies(.so shared objects) are compiled with 32 bit jvm, so it gives the error as you got. You need to recompiled the hadoop native libraries and then all your services will be up & running.

Check this out for solution:

http://kuntalganguly.blogspot.in/2014/07/building-native-hadoop-libraries-to-fix.html

Answer (score 0):

There are also PPAs:

```
ppa:hadoop-ubuntu/dev
ppa:hadoop-ubuntu/testing
ppa:hadoop-ubuntu/stable
```

See here for more information: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/Hadoop